# Java Integer overflow product in a long integer

Tags: java, overflow

I have this silly question.

```
long val = Integer.MIN_VALUE * -1;
System.out.println(val);
```

Why does this print `-2147483648`.

A `long` should be able to accommodate the above product, right? Shouldn't the output be `2147483648`

Comment: Yes, but `Integer.MIN_VALUE * -1;` is still calculated as `int`, before it's assigned to `long`. You need to either cast `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `long` or multiply it with `-1L` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product is computed as an `int` and then converted to `long`. But if one operand is long the result is the expected one.

Change `-1` to `-1L` to compute as a `long`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long val = Integer.MIN_VALUE * -1;
    long longVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE * -1L;
    System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    System.out.println(val);
    System.out.println(longVal);
}
```

The output is

```
-2147483648
-2147483648
2147483648
```

Comment: I got that part, else the answer would be +ve. So is every multiplication of whole numbers treated as an int unless explicitly specified?

Comment: Got it, that is what I was looking for, thank you! I should've clarified in my question, based on the error I get what is happening but wanted to understand the correct behavior!

Comment: re *So is every multiplication of whole numbers treated as an int unless explicitly specified?*  No.  (1) LIterals are **int** unless suffixed by L, which makes them **long**.  (2)  Arithmetic on **int** values gives an **int** result.  (3)  Arithmetic operations where one operand is **int** and the other **long** will first widen the **int** to **long**.